# No 'Hardware' tab in audio and no profiles

Tags: sound, hardware, pulseaudio

If I run the 12.x ubuntu (latest May 2012) from the CD, I get full audio settings, and sound playing in speaker. Profiles let me change analog to digital in/out.

Once I run install from the same CD onto the laptop HD, once it boots the first time, after selecting audio settings, there is no 'Hardware' tab and no way to change profiles.

Worst part is the audio device is set to SPDIF so nothing comes out of the speakers. Very off how booting off the CD I can get analog audio, and installing to HD and booting seems to limit the profile to something useless.

Laptop is a 5 year old Dell D820 with Nvidea 128meg video on a 1920x1200 screen and T7200 CPU.

I suspect if I could get the damn HARDWARE tab back in audio settings, I could just select the proper Analog profile - just as is the case if running from a boot CD.

Searched the web, no similar problems found... any help appreciated!

Comment: What drivers are installed for the Nvidia graphics?